# ThymeLeaf pass variable to vue js

Tags: vuejs2, thymeleaf

Thymeleaf th:attr not working with Vue bind property

```
<truncate th:attr="'v-bind:text'=${message}"/>
```

The above line not giving me error in both Vue and Thymeleaf but nothing display on page

below is the response from server side

[image: Attached image showing perfect response from server side]

Once I remove 'v-bind:' prefix and use some thing like "th:attr="text=${user.comment}" its working as expected

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 row_block_padding" th:each="user : ${response.users}">

    <!-- OTHER CODE -->
    <div class="col-lg-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10" style="padding-top: 15px;">
        <truncate th:attr="text=${user.comment}"></truncate>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What version of Thymeleaf?

Comment: thymeleaf 3.0.9.RELEASE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to use the `th:attr` directive. For example

```
<div th:with="message='Simple message'">
  <truncate th:attr="'v-bind:text'=${message}"/>
</div>
```

See https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#setting-the-value-of-any-attribute

---

**Update:** to use `th:attr` with HTML5 invalid attributes (like `v-bind:text`), you need to quote the attribute name (fixed above).

This produces the following markup

```
<div>
  <truncate v-bind:text="Simple Message"/>
</div>
```

You may note that this is not a valid Vue binding expression so perhaps you don't actually want to use binding and instead use

```
<truncate th:attr="text=${message}"/>
```

which would produce

```
<truncate text="Simple message"/>
```

Comment: Getting below error with above statement:  org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as assignation sequence: "v-bind:text=${message}"

Comment: @PankajPatel ah, oops. That's what I get for not testing. Please see my updated answer

Comment: Unfortunately its also not working. I tried with below and its giving me output as expected   <truncate th:attr="text=${message}"></truncate>

Comment: @PankajPatel I tested with Thymeleaf 3.0.9.RELEASE and it worked just fine. Could you please update the code in your question to match what you currently have?

Comment: Current code is working:


<div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 row_block_padding" th:each="user : ${response.users}">

    <!-- OTHER CODE -->
 <div class="col-lg-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10" style="padding-top: 15px;">
  <truncate th:attr="text=${user.comment}"></truncate>
 </div>
</div>

Comment: @PankajPatel **Please update the code in your question**. Also, that looks nothing like my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178058/discussion-between-pankaj-patel-and-phil).

Comment: @PankajPatel sounds like you got there in the end. I've explained in my answer already why `v-bind:text` wouldn't have been working.

Answer (score 0):

```
<truncate th:attr="'v-bind='{text:'+${message}+'}'"/>
```

the solution of vue: another usage of v-bind

> https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind